# The 'open <folder>' command in Terminal and the 'Reveal file in Finder' option aren't working

Tags: terminal, finder, filesystem, spotlight

If you search for a file in Spotlight and command-click the file you expect the Finder to activate and show that file. Instead, the Finder activates but only shows my home folder.

Same thing in Terminal:

```
open /Users/myHome/Documents/aa/ab
```

Will activate the Finder but with a window on `/Users/myHome/`. Same thing with any open file: if you command-click on the file name on top of the file window you can select any folder on its path to have it open in Finder. Instead, the Finder opens `/Users/myHome/`.

Same thing with several applications that tell the Finder to reveal a file (not all apps: Music will correctly reveal track in Finder).

I have tried rebuilding the *Spotlight index*, checking the disk with Disk Utility, reinstalling Big Sur 11.4 but that does not fix the issue.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: This is kind of an old-school trick, so I don't know if it still applies in Big Sur, but have you tried deleting the Finder preferences ('~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist')? In older OSes that file would sometimes get corrupted, producing weird Finder behaviors. Drop the file in the trashcan and the relaunch the Finder; you may lose some finder preferences.

Comment: It worked! Many thanks. Feel free to make that an answer, I will accept it gladly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested by @TedWrigley: just delete the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`. This can be achived throught the Terminal:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

Worked great.